# PDF file in lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a PDF file in S3.  eg. original.pdf

1. use s3.getObject to get information of original.pdf
2. generate an empty new pdf file ex)new.pdf
3. i want to copy contents of original.pdf to new.pdf
4. want to put the password in new.pdf
5. use s3.putObject to upload new.pdf

please help me

```js
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const PDFLIB = require('pdf-lib');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {

        let params = {
            Bucket : 'bucket-name',
            Key : 'key'
        };

        s3.getObject(params,(err,data)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err,err.stack);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        const pdfDoc = PDFLIB.create();
    }
```

i think i made step 1
and then i want to generate a new pdf for copying the original pdf.

but in lambda there is an error

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "PDFLIB.create is not a function",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: PDFLIB.create is not a function",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/test2.js:20:27)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have things pretty well broken down. Why don't you try looking up how to apply a password to a pdf then write it out, and put it in s3.

Comment: @HSchmale i have to protect the original file in s3. when a customer buy my pdf file then i have to make a clone pdf file and apply a password in the clone file.

Comment: @신상택 I don't dive in to the logic of your use case. But I have a question where do you get your error. It looks like you try to run the published lambda, and I think by publishing the lambda function, you forgot to deploy dependencies (node_modules)

Comment: @elbik i have deployed dependency correctly. maybe there is a problem in this module i think. I got an error in the published lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the `PDFDocument` while requiring `pdf-lib`. check the documentation for more details. the code will be like this

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { PDFDocument} = require('pdf-lib');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {

        let params = {
            Bucket : 'bucket-name',
            Key : 'key'
        };

        s3.getObject(params,(err,data)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err,err.stack);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        const pdfDoc = PDFDocument.create(); // this is a async function as per documentation so need to await it or use then after that.
    }
```

Hope this works. Note that `create` method is async as per documentation.

Comment: THX! it works! now i have to learn the different of 'const { PDFDocument} = require('pdf-lib') ' and 'const PDFDocument = require('pdf-lib');'